# StaxItemReader to read and print the values

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am learning spring batch now. I wanted to use StaxEventItemReaderto read xml file
So I just tried using it in standalone java file in java perspective with all necessary spring jars.

I want to know how can I  ensure whether it has read the values and what values it has read . In short I want to print the read values in console . How can I do it in standalone java file?

### Code as follows:

```
    main(){
    StaxEventItemReader<Student> xmlFileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<Student>();
    xmlFileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/Student.xml"));
    xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("Marks");

    Jaxb2Marshaller medicareMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    medicareMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Student.class);
    xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(medicareMarshaller);
    System.out.println(xmlFileReader. ?);
}
```

Please help me in knowing how to print the read values. I apologise if my content is not clear. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How about Junit?

Comment: Googling for 'test spring batch program' can give you some useful starting points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my adapted code below.
Generally, if you want to test SpringBatch components without having them instantiated as Spring-Beans (-> by calling der Constructor directly), you should call the "afterPropertiesSet()" method, after you have called all your set-Methods.

Next, depending on the reader/writers you want to test directly, you have to call reader.open(new ExecutionContext()).

After that, you can call the read()-method, which should then return item after item.

```
main(){
StaxEventItemReader<Student> xmlFileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<Student>();
xmlFileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/Student.xml"));
xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("Marks");

Jaxb2Marshaller medicareMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
medicareMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Student.class);
xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(medicareMarshaller);

xmlFileReader.afterPropertiesSet(); // in the case of StaxEventItemReader not really necessary

xmlFileReader.open(new ExecutionContext()); // does some initialisation, so you need to call it

Studen student = null;
while(student = xmlFileReader.read() != null) {
    System.out.println(student...);   
}

xmlFileReader.close();
```

Comment: If you get a chance please try to look at my another thread posted over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903518/spring-batch-staxitemreader-jaxb-to-read-multiple-nested-xml-nodes