# Spring Batch -- StaxItemReader Jaxb to read multiple nested xml nodes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, spring-batch

Iam trying to read xml file which has nested xml nodes using StaxEventItemReader and Jaxb2Marshaller. some where iam doing something wrong which result in exception.

Will provide sample XML file here

**File.xml**

```
    <File>
        <FileDate>05/28/2016</FileDate>
        <RecordCount>75</RecordCount>
        <Transaction>
           <RecordID>1</RecordID>
           <MemberDetails>
               <Id>A2334549</Id>
               <MemberDemoData>
                   <SubID>89890734548557</SubID>
                   <MemberSuffix>01</MemberSuffix>
                   <SSN>XXXXX</SSN>
                   <CategoryCode>B</CategoryCode>
                   <Gender>F</Gender>
                   <LastName>Naaz</LastName>
                   <FirstName>Affu</FirstName>
                   <MiddleInitial>H</MiddleInitial>
                   <BirthDate>04/02/1990</BirthDate>
                   <HICNumber>4567376739A</HICNumber>
                   <PhoneNumber>894567893</PhoneNumber>
                   <ProviderID>09678546</ProviderID>
                   <PCPOverride>N</PCPOverride>
                   <Address>
                       <AddressType>HOME</AddressType>
                       <Address1>2226 Indira nagar RD</Address1>
                       <City>Noida</City>
                       <State>Delhi</State>
                       <Zip>525001</Zip>
                       <County>India</County>
                   </Address>
                   <Address>
                       <AddressType>MAIL</AddressType>
                       <Address1>2226 Indira nagar RD</Address1>
                       <City>Noida</City>
                       <State>Delhi</State>
                       <Zip>525001</Zip>
                       <County>India</County>
                   </Address>
                   <AgentInfo>
                       <MailAgentNo>40</MailAgentNo>
                       <AgentNo>67894</AgentNo>
                   </AgentInfo>
              </MemberDemoData>
              <Package>
                 <Plan>Yu8883</Plan>
                 <PlanId>009</PlanId>
                 <SegmentId>104</SegmentId>
                 <Group>000987666</Group>
                 <SubGroup>B004</SubGroup>
                 <Class>0004</Class>
                 <PartD>
                     <BIN>789034</BIN>
                     <PCN>*******</RxPCN>
                 </PartD>
                 <EffectiveDate>09/01/2016/01/2016</EffectiveDate>
                 <TerminationDate>12/31/2016</TerminationDate>
             </Package>
             <LICSInfo>
                 <SubsidyLevel>100</SubsidyLevel>
                 <CopayCategory>1</CopayCategory>
                 <SubsidyLevelStartDate>08/11/2016</SubsidyLevelStartDate>
             </LICSInfo>
             <MedihealthData>
                    <PartA>
                       <EffectiveDate>02/01/2008</EffectiveDate>
                    </PartA>
                    <PartB>
                       <EffectiveDate>02/01/2008</EffectiveDate>
                    </PartB>
                    <ESignDate>
                       <EffectiveDate>08/16/2016</EffectiveDate>
                    </ESignDate>
            <ElectionPeriod>S</ElectionPeriod>
                    <EnrollmentDate>
                       <EffectiveDate>08/01/2016</EffectiveDate>
                    </EnrollmentDate>
               </MedihealthData>
               <BillingData>
                    <PremiumWithHold>D</PremiumWithHold>
               </BillingData>
           </MemberDetails>
        </Transaction>
        <Transaction>
         -------
        </Transaction>
        <Transaction>
         ------
        </Transaction>
        <Transaction>
         -------
        </Transaction>
    </File>
```

And have Jaxb Classes for --> File, Transaction, MemberDetails, MemberDemoData, Address, AgentInfo,Package,  PartD, LICSInfo, MedihealthData, PartA, PartB, ESignDate, EnrollmentDate, BillingData

Sample Class

1. **File.java**

   ```
          @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
       "fileDate",
       "recordCount",
       "Transaction"
   })
   @XmlRootElement(name = "File")
   class File{
       @XmlElement(name = "FileDate", required = true)
       protected String fileDate;
       @XmlElement(name = "RecordCount", required = true)
       protected String recordCount;
       @XmlElement(name = "Transaction")
       protected List<Transaction> transaction;

   //setters and getters
   }
   ```

Where File.java is root class for all xml elements

Repeated element in File is Transaction

2. **Transaction.java**

   ```
   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
       "recordID",
       "memberDetails"
   })
   @XmlRootElement(name = "MPTransaction")

   public class Transaction {

       @XmlElement(name = "RecordID", required = true)
       protected String recordID;
       @XmlElement(name = "MemberDetails", required = true)
       protected MemberDetails memberDetails;
   // setter and getter

   }
   ```

Now I have written the ItemReader method in my SpringBatch

**ItemReader method to read File.xml**

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<File> fileXmlReader(@Value("#{stepExecution}") StepExecution stepExecution) {

            StaxEventItemReader<File> xmlFileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();

            xmlFileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/File.xml"));

            xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementNames(new String[] {"Transaction" , "MemberDetails" ,
                    "MemberDemoData", "Address" ,"AgentInfo","Package" , "PartD" ,"LICSInfo" , "MedihealthData",
                    "PartA", "PartB","ESignDate","EnrollmentDate","BillingData"} );

            Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
            marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Transaction.class,MemberDetails.class,
                    MemberDemoData.class,Address.class,AgentInfo.class,Package.class,
                    PartD.class,LICSInfo.class,MedihealthData.class,PartA.class,PartB.class,
                    ESignDate.class,EnrollmentDate.class,BillingData.class);

            xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);

            return xmlFileReader;

    }
```

If I run my Batch iam getting the below exception. Please help me in identifying where iam going wrong ?

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.moveCursorToNextFragment(StaxEventItemReader.java:151)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.doRead(StaxEventItemReader.java:228)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:155)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:114)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:386)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:210)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:227)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:121)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:115)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:672)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:690)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
        at com.bcn.medicareEnrollment.Runner.main(Runner.java)
```

Please help me out to sort out this issue. Iam new to Spring batch . when I run this xml reader logic im getting exception.

Comment: I looks like the internal reader of the StaxEventItemReader was not initialized. make a breakpoint at line 151 and check that. If it really is null, this means, that doOpen has not been called, resp. that it was not able to inialize the reader completely. again, make a breakpoint in do open and have look what is going on.

Comment: The breakpoint is not executing also how to keep break point for do open  as its internal class code of StaxEventItemReader

Comment: You can set a breakpoint in almost every library, just download the code together with the library (resp. tell maven to download it with the binaries).  I would recommend, that you do a little research on how to use breakpoints in your IDE. Especially, what kind of breakpoints are available, what kind of information you can get as soon as you are in a breakpoint, etc. I'm sure, there are a couple of tutorials and youtube videos. This is really  basic craftmanship you have to master. It will make you more productive, it will help you to understand third party code, ...