# Can i use spring ItemProcessor from spring batch standalone?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

My requirement is to read CSV,XML,JSON, excel file format through file upload functionality using spring controller. Read the file transform and save into the database.

I want to use genericItem processor like Spring Batch ItemProcessor to read the above file formats. My transform logic will be common for all and then save it to the Database.

Is there any way by which i can use spring batch ItemProcessor in standalone way without creating the batch job or is there any open source tool which can read the file in above formats?

Comment: Try apache Camel. Camel is an open source integration framework that empowers you to quickly and easily integrate various systems consuming or producing data.

Comment: What do you mean by using Spring Batch ItemProcessor standalone? `ItemProcessor` is an interface. If you mean using Spring Batch components (readers, writers, etc) without creating jobs, then yes it is possible. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834093/staxitemreader-to-read-and-print-the-values

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache camel to get the desired flow. There are lot of code examples out in internet to configure apache camel with spring-boot. 
Here in this example, I assume that data is posted to `/csv` , `/excel` , `/xml` end points and data is routed to `direct:records`. From `direct:records` we have a custom processor to process the data. We can have multiple steps like that.

```
@Component
public class StudentRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        restConfiguration()
                .component("servlet")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

        rest("/student").produces("application/json")
                .post("/csv").to("direct:records")
                .post("/excel").to("direct:records")
                .post("/xml").to("direct:records");

        from("direct:records")
                .process(new Processor() {

                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        Object value = exchange.getIn().getBody(Object.class);
                        //write your logic here
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Also follow this link to get more about Apache Camel. [Spring Boot, Apache Camel, and Swagger UI](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-apache-camel-and-swagger-ui-1)